# Misaligned Link Text in Close Dialog

Tags: support, bug, close-dialog

In `Stack Overflow` question closing dialog, link texts like `SSCCE.org`, `Super User` were misaligned.

The issue is happening, only if there is at-least one vote for that particular category.

**Issue 1:**
[image: SSCCE.org]

**Issue 2:**
[image: Super User]